# Validate associated models in ActiveRecord (has_many through)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to be able to create and edit a model together with associated many-to-many entities.
Related objects should be joined through a model with additional fields and integrity validations (e.g. uniqueness or presence).
I want to check the integrity with standard validation mechanism provided by Rails.

An example would be a `Post` (like here on Stackoverflow), with at least one `Tag` and no more than 3 `Tags`. `Tag` cannot be assigned more than once to single `Post`.
Additionally, the tags will be ordered (`priority` in the join table).

The model should use custom validators with `validates` and add error messages to `Post#errors` if any constraint is violated.
On edit, the model and it's relation to `Tag` (`TagAssignment`) won't be saved if any validation fails (e.g. post title was removed or too many tags were added).

Example model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_assignments
  has_many :tags, :through => :tag_assignments

  validates :title,
            presence: true
  validates :content,
            presence: true
  validates :number_of_tags

  def number_of_tags
    valid = self.tags.count.in? 1..3
    errors.add('error: 1 <= tag.size <= 3') unless valid
    valid
  end
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_assignments
  has_many :posts, through: :tag_assignment

  validates :name,
            presence: true
end

class TagAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tag

  validates :tag_id,
            uniqueness: {scope: :post_id}
  validates :priority,
            presence: true,
            uniqueness: {scope: :tag_id}
end
```

Example usage:

```
post = Post.build(title: 'title', content: 'content')
post.save # false
post.errors # contains message: 'error: 1 <= tag.size <= 3'
post.tagger << Tag.first
post.save # true
post_id = post.id

post = Post.find(post_id)
post.tagger << Tag.all[5..10]
post.save # false
          # but tag_assignments were already created
          # and old TagAssignments were not destroyed
```

(in the example I assumed that `tagger` is a method which builds `TagAssignments` with set `priority`)

What is the best design pattern to manage habtm relations and take benefit from built in validation system?

Comment: Refer this answer. I think this is what you need.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290752/rails-error-message-using-fields-for/18291435#18291435

Answer (score 0):

The solution I needed was to use `.build` instead of `<<`.

```
post = Post.build(title: 'title', content: 'content')
post.tag_assignments.build(tag: Tag.first, priority: 1)
post.save # true, TagAssignments are persisted here
post_id = post.id
```

There is still a problem of orphans when replacing old assignments which remains unsolved for me:

```
post.tag_assignments = [TagAssignment.new(tag: Tag.first, priority: 1)]  # an update on assignments sets user_id = NULL and new assignment is inserted
post.title = nil
post.valid? # false, but correct TagAssignments were replaced with new ones
```